# Как в shell скрипте Linux проследить за попытками подключения по TCP с указанного адреса?

Tags: linux, bash, tcp, iptables

Необходимо проследить за попытками соединения по протоколу TCP с указанного адреса (iptables: -syn ). И разрешить не более 10 соединений в час.
Пытался написать анализатор через подключений ipconfig, сделать таблицу для адресов, воткнуть таймеры, и через iptables запретить подключения, но, походу мой подход совсем не правильный(((

Comment: Возможно, подойдёт просто --limit 10/hour в соответствующем правиле iptables? Типа -p tcp -s source_address --state NEW --limit 10/hour -j ACCEPT

Comment: -m ещё добавить

Comment: есть ещё ipset с таймерами

Comment: Это делается без всяких скриптов, только средствами firewall.